# When I try to create a relationship for a user in gorm, I get an "Unknown column" error

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to get the followers by preparing the users table and the followers table.
The users table and the followers table look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    id bigint(20) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE follows (
    id bigint(20) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    follower_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    followee_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    created_at datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (follower_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (followee_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    UNIQUE ( follower_id, followee_id )
);
```

The model defined in gorm is as follows.

```golang
type User struct {
    ID            uint
    CreatedAt     time.Time
    UpdatedAt     time.Time
    Name          string
    Followers     []*User `gorm:"many2many:follows;joinForeignKey:followee_id;JoinReferences:following_id;"`
}
```

`db.DB.First(&user, id).Related(&user.Followers, "Followers")`

If you try to get the followers associated with a user in this way
will result in an error.

```
 Error 1054: Unknown column 'follows.user_id' in 'where clause'
```

It looks like the foreign key setting is not working, but I don't know how to solve it.
I would appreciate it if you could help me.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `.Related()` is only found on gorm v1, but you are using tags like `joinForeignKey` and `joinReferences` that appear only in the v2 docs. Can you confirm which version of gorm you're using?